# Haxe to SWC - protected getters/setters

Tags: actionscript-3, getter-setter, haxe, swc

I am porting a library from AS3 to Haxe and I need to make protected getters/setters. Target is a *.swc file.

My Haxe code looks like this:

```
private var foo(get, never):Int;
@:getter(foo)
private function get_foo():Int {
    return 0;
}

private var bar:Int;
```

However the produced *.swc file is a little different:

```
native public function get foo():int;
native protected var bar:int;
```

Is there any known workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `@:getter` and `-D swf-protected` (or `@:protected`) don't play well together.  Only one or the other is applied...

Example:

```
class Test {
    var foo(get, never):Int;
    @:protected @:getter(foo) private function get_foo():Int return 0;
    var bar(get, never):Int;
    @:getter(bar) @:protected private function get_bar():Int return 0;
}
```

generates:

```
protected function get get_foo() : int { return 0; }
public function get bar() : int { return 0; }
```

You should open an issue on the [official repository](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues).

Answer (score 0):

You could try add **swf-protected** [global compiler flag](https://haxe.org/manual/compiler-usage-flags.html)

Comment: Already added, that's why the `bar` var came out `protected`.